# Kotlin enforce argument type to be a String, Boolean or Number

Tags: generics, kotlin, primitive-types

I have a usecase where I send some data to my server (as analytics) which is always either `String`, `Boolean` or `Number`.

How can I enforce the caller to send only a number, boolean or string and NOT any other objects?

Following cases should work-

```
userProperties: MutableMap<String, in AnyPrimitive> = mutableMapOf(),

userProperties.put("someKey", 1)
userProperties.put("someKey", 1.2f)
userProperties.put("someKey", "someValue")
userProperties.put("someKey", true)
```

but not

```
userProperties.put("someKey", myCustomObjectInstance)
```

Approach I tried was creating an abstract class `EventData` which implements `CharSequence` and `Number`. But this requires everyone to create an instance of these class and not send simply a number or a string.

I can put a logic to check the type and throw exception but I would prefer restricting it at compile time.

Comment: just provide 3 overloads.

Comment: @al3c I wanted to make the question simpler so ended up writing dummy code. Updatetd the question.

Comment: In that case a `sealed class` with 3 implementations should do.

Comment: @al3c But in that case devs will have to pass the instance of those classes instead of passing simply primitive. If I am missing something, pls post it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Note: if you _enforce the caller to send only a number, boolean or string_, they still will able to send `Any` object by using the following adapter: `class ToNumberAdapter(val actualObject: Any) : Number() { // Number methods implementations }`

Comment: @Bananon good catch. But now since I've decided to go ahead with annotations, I can very well put the logic there to check for this.

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion is something like this:

```kotlin
sealed class Data {
    class StringData(val s: String): Data()
    class NumberData(val n: Int): Data()
    class BooleanData(val b: Boolean): Data()
    companion object {
        fun of(s: String) = StringData(s)
        fun of(n: Int) = NumberData(n)
        fun of(b: Boolean) = BooleanData(b)
    }
}
```

Then your snippet becomes:

```
userProperties: MutableMap<String, Data> = mutableMapOf(),

userProperties.put("someKey", Data.of(1))
userProperties.put("someKey", Data.of("someValue"))
userProperties.put("someKey", Data.of(true))
```

to what extent this is feasible really depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: The problem with this is devs have to use Data.of() every time they want to add something. Not as simple as using directly the primitives, which was my main question.

Comment: @Rajkiran you can create the following extension methods: `operator fun <K> MutableMap<K, Data>.set(key: K, string: String) { this[key] = Data.of(string) }`, `operator fun <K> MutableMap<K, Data>.set(key: K, number: Number) { this[key] = Data.of(number) }`, and `operator fun <K> MutableMap<K, Data>.set(key: K, boolean: Boolean) { this[key] = Data.of(boolean) }`

Comment: @Bananon this is actually smart. The only catch here is people will have to call this extension method every time instead of simply putting the value inside. But still a good one.

Comment: @Rajkiran do you think that calling an extension method is less convenient than calling a member method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify from a usage point of view, declare the send function like so:

```
fun send(arg: Any) {
    //Validations here:
    if (!validate(arg)) throw IllegalArgumentException("...")

    //Actual send code here...
}

private fun validate(arg: Any): Boolean {
    return (arg is String || arg is Boolean || arg is Number)
}
```

Do note that this not being enforced at compile time but is a run time failure. So if somebody codes up a

```
send(RandomObject)
```

The compile will succeed. At runtime it will fail though.

Comment: Bad idea to let it fail in runtime. Better to fail during compilation phase.

Answer (score 0):

Three overloads as per the comment of al3c. There is no way of achieving what you specify with generics in kotlin.

```
fun send(arg: Number) {
    // send
}

fun send(arg: Boolean) {
    // send
}

fun send(arg: String) {
    // send
}

// Many properties gathered in map described below
fun send(arg: EventData) {
    // send
}
```

If you want to use a map-object to send analytics. This needs a new class to contain the three overloads above. To constrain the user of this class from adding anything of the wrong class.

```
class EventData {

    // Or depending on other requirements you could use three maps with specific type
    private val analyticsData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

    fun put(key: String, arg: Number) {
         analyticsData.put(key, arg)
    }

    fun put(key: String, arg: Boolean) {
         analyticsData.put(key, arg)
    }

    fun put(key: String, arg: String) {
         analyticsData.put(key, arg)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, I think I wasn't clear in my question. I have updated the question and have also posted a possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61077530/840669

Answer (score 0):

It should've crossed my mind earlier. I can write custom annotation and annotation processor which will check for the type of the parameter at compile time. Something like this-

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SupportedTypes {

  Class<?>[] types() default {};
}
```

And write a custom annotation processor which will check for the types of all items passed in `types()`.

I will udpate the answer when I write the custom annotation processor. Meanwhile you can refer [How to write custom annotation processor](https://medium.com/androidiots/writing-your-own-annotation-processors-in-android-1fa0cd96ef11)